# Tortoise SubWCRev.exe custom Keywords

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

at the moment im versioning my Project with Tortoise and SubWCRev.exe like this:

> [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.3.0.0")]
>
> [assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.3.$WCDATE=%y%m$.$WCREV$")]

but i would like to change the BuildNr with a specific number like 12...13...14... so that it looks like 1.3.12.21432 or whatever.

So the question is: is it possibly to add some custom keywords or parameters ? Or are there any other solutions?
We are using Jenkins to Build our Projects.

Answer (score 2):

If BuildNr have to be some incrementing number, you can

1. Use `$WCREV-$` SubWCRev's default keyword with some "base" Revision as zero-point. For builds "on source change" you'll get incrementing revision of WC and incrementing `REV-BASE`
2. You can construct `AssemblyVersion` by hand|additional script and use [defined by Jenkins environment variable](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables) BUILD_NUMBER